# ag-grid react How to handle data with checkbox

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

i would like to get data when click on checkbox

i have tried used onCellClicked
i recive data on function onCellClick when click on row

but is nothing when i click on checkbox

Which props should I use?

```
export const DataTable = ():JSX.Element=> {
  ...
   const header = [
    {
     headerName: 'Select',
     field: 'selectBox',
     headerCheckboxSelection: true,
     headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
     checkboxSelection: true
   },
   {
    headerName: name,
    field: 'name',
    sortable: true,
    filter: true
   }

   const onCellClick = (e: CellClickedEvent) => {
     const data = e.data
   }

   return (
     <AgGridReact
      columnDefs={header}
      onGridReady={onGridReady}
      rowData={data}
      rowSelection="mutiple"
      animateRows={true}
      suppressRowClickSelection={true}
      rowMultiSelectWithClick={true}
      onCellClicked={onCellClick}
    />
   )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onRowSelected` instead of `onCellClicked`.

As per docs: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/grid-events/#reference-selection

> rowSelected   Row is selected or deselected.